# How to reduce docker image size for CentOS 7?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, centos7

I have recently started working on docker and I am trying to build a custom image for CentOS using CentOS:7.5.1804 image.

The problem I am facing here is that the original CentOS:7.5.1804 image is showing size 200MB and after I add the desired packages, the size of image becomes 1.2 GB! I am trying to figure out if there is a way to reduce the image size?

I tried using `yum clean all` & `rm -rf /var/cache/yum` in my dockerfile, however it barely reduced few MBs and it didn't helped much.

Any inputs/suggestions/best practices to reduce image size are welcome. My docker file is as shown below, which results into a 1.2GB image!

```
#Use CentOS as base
FROM centos:7.5.1804

# Docker recommends
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

# Install custom tools
RUN yum -y install openssl && yum install -y nc && \
yum -y install python3 && pip3 install j2cli && \
yum -y install epel-release &&  yum -y update && yum install -y ccrypt && \
yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some unnecessary instructions, Could you try with this Dockerfile?

```
#Use CentOS as base
FROM centos:7.5.1804

# Install custom tools
RUN yum -y install openssl ccrypt nc epel-release python3 && \
    pip3 install j2cli && \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm, reducing the image size to 276 MB straight away. Please note one change, have to move ccrypt installation out from the first group and install it separately, as ccrypt comes from epel-release package. `RUN yum -y install openssl nc epel-release python3 && yum -y install ccrypt \
    pip3 install j2cli && \
    yum clean all && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
`. Still trying to understand, what was wrong with the instructions we removed from dockerfile?

Comment: Remember every instruction of your Dockerfile creates a unique layer, so if you delete or clean some files,
(like ```yum clean all```) the change only affects the size of this layer but size of the previous layers will follow same, 
By last in your Dockerfile you was creating a unnecessary layer ```RUN yum -y update && yum clean all```